# Определение типа речи

Tags: стилистика

Есть ли в предложении 22 повествование?

> (21)Одним из семи чудес света, о которых писали древние, был александрийский маяк - сооружение грандиозное и необычное. (22)Рассказывают, что сферическое зеркало маяка под определённым углом собирало в пучок столько солнечного света, что могло сжигать корабли, плывущие далеко в море. (23)Маяк был построен по приказу Птолемея Филадельфа. (24)На мраморных плитах маяка самолюбивый фараон приказал выбить своё имя.

Comment: Какие еще типы речи могут быть в ответе?

Comment: Александрийский маяк — название. Пишется с прописной.

Answer (score 2):

Вот это задание в сети: https://znanija.com/task/25442150.

Есть ли в предложении 22 повествование?

> (22)Рассказывают, что сферическое зеркало маяка под определённым углом собирало в пучок столько солнечного света, что могло сжигать корабли, плывущие далеко в море.

Есть [три типа речи](http://school-of-inspiration.ru/tipy-rechi-povestvovanie-opisanie-rassuzhdenie): повествование, описание, рассуждение.
Предложение 22 соответствует определению **описания**:

> Описание – это словесное изображение предмета, явления, события. В описании перечисляются и раскрываются основные признаки выбранного предмета. Цель – представить читателю текста образ, который легко вообразить в красках. Важны единство времени и места проявления признаков.

Элемент, который может навести на мысль о повествовании, — это слово *рассказывают*, но его явно недостаточно.

> Повествование – это рассказ о событии, которое происходит в определенный промежуток времени.

В предложении 22 ни о каком событии не рассказано. **Ответ: повествования нет**.

Comment: Согласна, повествования нет, есть элемент описания.